# Local variance derivation by Gatheral

Tags: implied-volatility, local-volatility

I've bought Gatheral's book on Local Volatility and I have troubles with understanding a part where he shows that local variance is a conditional expectation of instantaneous variance.

Why in the second equation from the bottom he just skips the term $\theta (S_T-K)dS_T$? He says that it's because $F_{t,T}$ is a martingale. I see that $F_{t,T}$ is a martingale, but don't know how this helps. Also , what "condiational expectations" is he talking about? The notation looks a bit sloppy. Thanks for help.

[image]

http://www.math.ku.dk/~rolf/teaching/ctff03/Gatheral.1.pdf

Comment: From equation (9) $dF_{TT} = \sqrt{v_T} F_{T,T} dZ$ with $Z$ a standard Brownian motion. Now since $dF_{TT} = dS_T$ by absence of arbitrage, you see that when you take the expectation of the penultimate equation, the first term is zero by the properties of the Brownian motion (the integrated version would be to say that that an Itô integral has zero expectation).

Comment: I think one should be very careful with that kind of "mathematical demonstration". They are not rigourous and written after the final result is known. There is nothing intuitive about them unless you already know the result.

Comment: Yes, as you say, it is a bit informal and not a rigorous calculation. 
For example you cannot just put in delta functions in the Ito lemma (This is allowed by the Tanaka extension though). 
You should see this as something to guide your intuition, more than a rigorous explanation. For the details you need to learn it somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason for that term to vanish is that you can write the expectation of the $dS_T = dF_{T,T}$ in term of conditional expectations. First, recall the tower property of conditional expectations

$$\mathbb{E}[X]=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X|Y]].$$

Then
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\left[ \theta (S_T - K) dS_T \right] & = \mathbb{E}\left[ \theta (F_{T,T} - K) dF_{T,T} \right] =  \mathbb{E}\left[ \mathbb{E}\left[ \theta (F_{T,T} - K) dF_{T,T} \Big \vert \mathcal{F}_T\right] \right] \\
& = \mathbb{E}\left[  \theta (S_{T} - K) 
\mathbb{E}\left[ dF_{T,T} \Big \vert \mathcal{F}_T\right] \right] 
\end{align}
$$
and since $F_{t,T}$ is a martingale, $\mathbb{E}\left[ dF_{T,T} \Big \vert \mathcal{F}_T\right] = 0$.

If someone finds that my reasoning has some "muddy" steps, I'd appreciate the correction, so I also get this right.

Answer (score 0):

Conditional expectations is with respect to the filtration of your pricing date $t \leq T$. Because $S$ is a martingale, you have
$$
\mathbb{E} \left[\theta \left(S_T - K\right) dS_T \middle\vert \mathcal{F}_t\right] = \mathbb{E} \left[\theta \left(S_T - K\right) \middle\vert \mathcal{F}_t\right] \mathbb{E} \left[d \, S_T\middle\vert \mathcal{F}_t\right]
$$
Remember that $S_T$ is $\mathcal{F}_T$-measurable, and increment $d\,S_T$ has to be dependent on $\mathcal{F}_T$ only through current value of the process $S_T$ ; to convince yourself, just rewrite
$$\theta \left(S_T - K\right) dS_T = \theta \left(S_T - K\right) \sigma_T S_T dW_T$$
and remember that Brownian motion increments are independent, hence $\mathbb{E} \left(dW_T \middle \vert \mathcal{F}_T\right) = \mathbb{E} \left(dW_T \middle \vert \mathcal{F}_t\right) = 0$.

That is why that term vanishes. The rest is straightforward.

Comment: However, to arrive to that step in Gatheral's there is no need to assume that $S_T$ is a martingale. Ideally I'd try to do it without assuming that $\mathbb{E} [ dS_T ] = 0$.

Comment: He uses the fact that $dF_{T,T} = dS_T$, and $F$ is a martingale under the risk-neutral measure!

Comment: Sure, sorry, I thought you meant the substitution of $dS_t$ to $dF_{t,T}$ applied for any $t$, and that's only true for $t = T$. My mistake.